# How to have a fresh lot of random integers each time a method is called?

Tags: java, android, random

I am pretty new at android development (and java) so the code I have written is not good, if you have any other suggestions to completely change my code and still serve the purpose then you're welcome. But for now I would like to know if I can make some random integers and randomize them again through a method. So I have a fresh lot of numbers to display each time the method is called.

Here's my code

```
public class Randomize {

//setting up random integers
int one = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*9+1);
int two = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*9+1);
int three = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*9+1);

//making a string for displaying it as a three-digit number
String number = "" + one + two + three;

//adding them up, which will make a two-digit integer
int sum = one + two + three;

//distinguishing two-digit integer
int firstDigit = (int) Math.floor(sum / 10);
int secondDigit = (int) (sum % 10);

//adding up to create a single-digit number
int singleDigit = firstDigit + secondDigit;

//creating methods
public void refreshNumbers(){
    //refresh random numbers
}

public String number(){
    return number;
}

public int singleDigit(){
    return singleDigit;
}
}
```

So you can see I add them up till a single digit comes up. Now I want to refresh the random numbers each time I call the method from another class.

Thanks a lot! Please let me know if you didn't understand the question...I am not good at explaining anyways, and neither at java :)

Answer (score 0):

Use one of various libraries or standard classes that provide random numbers. A common approach is to use [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28long%29), providing the current time (in milliseconds from Unix epoch) as the seed.

Whether you do this once per class, per method, per iteration doesn't matter, the same approach should work assuming sufficiently granular time can be retrieved quickly enough (if doing once per iteration for example).

Comment: +1 for using Random, but I would create only one Random instance (probably a static class variable, because of the better performance), and you can call the parameterless constructor - it's easier and better than giving the current milliseconds as seed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this?

```
public void refreshNumbers(){
    one = // new random number
    // etc.
}
```

Then just create an instance of your class, get the number, and then refresh it by called `refreshNumbers()`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to avoid repetition of random number when your method is invoked, why don't you try with SecureRandom which is better than Random as it provides a cryptographically strong random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Randomize {

    private int one, two, three, sum, firstDigit, secondDigit, singleDigit;

    private Random random = null;
    private String number = null;

    public Randomize(){
        random = new Random();
        refreshNumbers();
    }

    //creating methods
    public void refreshNumbers(){

        //setting up random integers
        one   = 1 + random.nextInt(9);
        two   = 1 + random.nextInt(9);
        three = 1 + random.nextInt(9);

        //adding them up, which will make a two-digit integer
        sum = one + two + three;

        //making a string for displaying it as a three-digit number
        number = Integer.toString(sum);

        //distinguishing two-digit integer
        firstDigit  = sum / 10;
        secondDigit = sum % 10;

        //adding up to create a single-digit number
        singleDigit = firstDigit + secondDigit;
    }

    public String getNumber(){
        return number;
    }

    public int getSingleDigit(){
        return singleDigit;
    }
}
```

It basically does the same thing, but moved all logic into your refreshNumbers method, initiates an instance of Random in a constructor, and also refreshes the numbers there. I only changed all random generation to instead use Random, moved the order of the calculations to reuse results, specified access restrictions on private variables and renamed functions to start with "get" when appropriate.